# Как получить значение из БД SQL? java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
 System.out.print("Введите имя: "); //начинаем регистрацию
            name = reader.readLine();
            System.out.print("Введите фамилию: ");
            sername = reader.readLine();
            System.out.print("Введите класс: ");
            grade = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            System.out.print("Введите букву класса: ");
            gradeLatter = reader.readLine();
            String login = sername +  name.toUpperCase().charAt( 0 )+grade;
            String loginQuery = "Select login from children.childrenInfo where name = ";
            //делаем запрос в БД с данными пользователя
            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement( "INSERT INTO children.childreninfo" +
                    " (name,sername,grade,gradeLatter,login) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" );
            ps.setString( 1, name );
            ps.setString( 2, sername );
            ps.setInt( 3, grade );
            ps.setString( 4,gradeLatter );
            ps.setString( 5,login );
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно реализовать запрос так, что бы ответом был логин только что зарегистрированного пользователя.
Я, скажем ввожу свои данные, и в конце после занесения в БД, мне выводиться логин.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно получить логин пользователя по его `id` вы можете это сделать так:

`select login from children where id = 100500`

этот запрос вернет логин для юзера с id = 100500.

Я смотрю что id у вас судя по всему генерируется автоматический, для этого нужно будет внести еще некоторые изменения в код.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO children.childreninfo" +
            " (name,sername,grade,gradeLatter,login) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);


    int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

    if (affectedRows == 0) {
        throw new SQLException("Ошибка");
    }

    try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
        if (generatedKeys.next()) {
            long id = generatedKeys.getLong(1);

            //делаем второй запрос что  бы узнать логин
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "select login from children where id = " + id;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while (rs.next()) {
                String registeredUserLogin = rs.getString("login");

                // принтим в консоль логин, только что зарегистрированного пользователя
                System.out.println("User registered with login: " + registeredUserLogin);
            }

        } else {
            throw new SQLException("Ошибка");
        }
    }
```

Comment: мне нужно получить логин сразу при регистрации, зарегистрировался и сразу выводиться логин на консоль

Comment: так... и в чем проблема это сделать? я добавил комментарий в коде где вы можете вызвать второй запрос и вывести в консоль то что вам нужно.

Comment: воот, уже близко к решению, как в запрос передать полученную переменную  с id?

Comment: Вы вынуждаете меня писать код вместо вас, я поправил свой ответ. Моменты типа закрытия ResultSet  и Statement  в коде опущены, смотреть примеры работы с JDBC https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-select-records.htm

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - это использовать *jdbc*. Пример с его использованием будет выглядеть так:

```
//зависит от версии драйвера, если используется относительно "свежий", 
//то эту строку можно пропустить
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("<url>", "<login>", "<password>");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT 1";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Comment: я и использую JDBC, вопрос в том что мне нужно указать sql запросом что нужно достать логины не все, а именно логин только что зарег. пользователя.

Comment: покажите структуру таблиц и как вы сохраняете данные

Comment: обновлено......

Comment: Если у вас id генерируется базой, то получить его можно будет после выполнения запроса вызовом метода ` Statement::getGeneratedKeys()`